# Insert statement to update destination database using linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I'm trying to insert/update all the 25 tables in `destinationDB` in SQL Server 2014 from `sourceDB` which is on SQL Server 2000 based on the `recid`.

I saw few examples on single table insert using the linked server. Can I update/insert all the tables in the database using below script. I need to do this for all the 25 tables. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I need to do achieve something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [DestinationDB]
    SELECT * 
    FROM SourceDB
    LEFT JOIN [DestinationDB] ON DestinationDB.recid = SourceDB.recid
    WHERE Destination.Recid IS NULL
```

Comment: NO. An insert statement is for a specific table. You can't just say insert these tables into those tables. It doesn't make any sense. You might want to look into export/importing data instead of doing this with straight sql.

Comment: @SeanLange- Thanks for the clarification.